# How to query sum field on mysql by month

Tags: php, mysql

Need help, friends. :)

Could you help me, please.

So, i've a table on mySQL. Preview like this :

```
MyDate            phone           name    costA   costB 
2011-09-13  0767657567567   Xyz     35  30
2011-09-24  0767657567567   Xyz     10  15
2011-09-26  0767657567567   Xyz     25  15
2011-09-27  081323232323    Abc     20  25
```

I want to make the query that execute by condition `WHERE MONTH(MyDate) = '9'` and result like this :

```
phone          name    sum(costA)  sum(costB)
0767657567567  Xyz     70          60  
081323232323   Abc     20          25
```

Coudl you tell me how the query of the result above?

Comment: What type has a MyDate? String or Date?

Comment: You can use BETWEEN in SQL queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
SELECT 
MONTH(MyDate), 
phone, 
name, 
sum(costA), 
sum(costB) 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MONTH(MyDate) = '9' 
GROUP BY MONTH(MyDate), phone, name
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure but you can try the following:

```
SELECT phone, name, sum(costA), sum(costB)
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(MyDate) = 9
GROUP BY phone, name
```

It's basically a simple GROUP BY clause that can do the sum according to the name that appears and if the month is 9. Let me know if it works.